# iMacros - extracting text

Tags: extract, imacros

Can you explain to me why my EXTRACT doesn't work? I am trying to count the number of users with private profiles in my group (because mostly these are bots). So I need to check whether the string "This profile is private" exists on the user's page.
After the code runs, a blue frame appears around the DIV which means the element is pinned correctly. However, the extract result is NaN.
I tried extracting both TXT and HTM.

```
 iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:This<SP>profile<SP>is<SP>private EXTRACT=TXT");
 var pageblock = parseInt (iimGetLastExtract());
  alert (pageblock);
```

An example page with a private profile:
https://vk.com/id646170325

I tried extracting both TXT and HTM.

Answer (score 0):

Yep normal..., no way you can convert the extracted `This profile is private` (is a `String`) to an `Integer`...!, ... which is what `parseInt()` is trying to do..., => Result = `NaN`...
=> The Behaviour/Result looks then "normal" to me...