# imacros - going back to TAB T=1

Tags: imacros

Why doesn't this code work in Firefox? Why doesn't it execute the last command and go back to Tab 1 in the end?

```
iimPlay ("CODE: TAB T=1");
iimPlay ("CODE: TAB OPEN");
iimPlay ("CODE: TAB T=2");
iimPlay ("CODE: URL GOTO=https://vk.com");
iimPlay ("CODE: TAB T=1");
```

I expected that Tab 1 will open again.

Comment: Yeah..., you would first need to follow up on your previous Qt for me to want to help you again, I posted an Answer about 10 days ago, but you didn't react/follow up at all (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71607011/3799241)... // + For both Qt's, you should read the [iMacros Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/imacros/info) for some missing Tech Info to include when you ask a Qt in the [tag:imacros] Tag... :idea:  // (I will downvote this Qt in 24h if you don't improve "the Quality" with the "Recommendations" from the Tag Wiki...) // + Your Post is full of Typos, can you correct them also...?

Comment: Also I have a cerebral paralysis fingers arn't very precise. But the instructions chivracq gave are obviously for people who know this site very well, - both Qt's,I am sorry for bothering. Thanks again for helping/

Comment: OK, quick Reply without starting a whole "Discussion", well the Instructions on the [iMacros Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/imacros/info) merely ask you to mention the 3 Versions about your FCI (Full Config Info), shouldn't be that "complicated"... => `iMacros for FF v8.9.7/v9.0.3...?, FF55/56...?, OS...?`. // + Probably related to your FCI, if you created your 2 Qt's using FF55/56, half of the Site Functionality doesn't work anymore in that Browser (Voting/Commenting/etc doesn't work...) // Typos: Well, try to "explain" Typos to a Compiler: => Syntax Error...!

Comment: => '-1' from me now... I gave the "Reasons" already..., still no Improvement to the Qt after 2d...

Comment: For Info, I've retracted my Downvote, thanks to some Edit by some High-Rep User, even if the Qt still doesn't meet my "Quality Standards" to post an Answer (FCI not mentioned, etc..., as the Post doesn't "comply" with the Recommendations from the Tag Wiki), but at least all Typos (in the Body) have now been corrected...